# Scientific Notation in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble, readr

I have the following situation: my file (mov.csv) have a column called "Id", like in the image:

[Img print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgkJX.png)

The situation: **When I parse the info from the file I need to maintain the length because the same "Id" is in other related tables (since this columns is the "key"), but R automatically change me column info to scientific notation!**, like in the following code result:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

mov <- read_csv("mov.csv")

mov
```

the result if I do not apply nothing:

[not using any option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mPBS.png)

I need to use Id column with the complete set of digits (19 digits), but R do not shows that... When I search for solutions, all are related to very short "scientific numbers", but it's not the case I though (there's a lot of "solutions" saying put in the header something like that:

```
mov$Id <- mov$Id %>% as.numeric() %>% print(digits = 19)
```

but it only transform the info to another more unsefull number, since performs a kind of rounding of the number:

[no solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HIVA.png)

what can I do? please, your help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `read_csv("mov.csv", col_types = list(Id=col_character())`. R can't store that many digits exactly as a numeric value so you need to keep it a character.

Comment: I really thank you @MrFlick your suggestion.... Thanks a lot! (resolved!)